# Language dependent DNN start page

Tags: internationalization, dotnetnuke, start-page

what is the best way to have langage specific start pages dependent on the browser settings of the user?

The way I found out was to specify a "DefaultPage" as my start page that only contains a "Redirector" Module. This module checks the browser's language settings and redirects to "Startseite" if the browser language is "de-DE", else to "Home".

Because in the mean time I get problems on this way I am looking for a better solution:

1.) How can I obtain the real URL the user enters before DNN maps it to the start page?
2.) or is there a DNN-specific way that does what I want?

I have DNN Version 7.3.3.118.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, what I understand is that you want site to display the page in language what browser is having.

There are language packages in DNN,install them these can help you.

the system checks preferred bowser language(s) of the user and tries to match with installed languages in your website. If there is a match, best match is used, otherwise site default language is presented.

https://www.dnnsoftware.com/answers/set-default-language-based-on-user-login-country-in-dnn